# Generate stl mesh from csv

Tags: python, numpy, stl-format

I have a csv file that encodes elevation data of a 9000x5000 resolution photo of a dam, and I want to generate an stl file that I can print on my 3d printer. The csv has 3 parameters: `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, where `X` & `Y` denote a pixel location on the photo and `Z` is the elevation of the topography at `Pixel (X,Y)`. 
I want a 3D stl file of the photo in question with the nooks, crannies, and hills denoted by the elevation data. I attempted to do this using the Python library `numpy-stl`, but I'm realizing that I just don't know enough about stl files to accomplish the print job.
Any information on how I can make this file, or on how stl files encode information would be remarkably helpful.

Comment: This is way too broad as written.  I'd suggest you look at "Creating Mesh Objects from a list of vertices and faces" section of the [`numpy-stl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-stl) documentation, and if you get stuck trying to generate the `faces` array, come back and you can at least ask a programming question.  That array is simply a list of vertices (which you have) that partition your surface into triangles.  You're lucky - you have a regular x-y grid to work with.  That partitioning algorithm shouldn't be to difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a collection of *vertices*. However, what STL encodes is a list of *triangles*. So what you need to do is to construct triangular mesh connecting your vertices. I assume that you want to code it yourself and I will provide you some hints on how to do it.

First, you should find out, whether your points are structured or not. By structured I mean that the *x*- and *y*-coordinates of the points form a regular grid (this is often the case when the data are obtained from airborne scanning).

### If the points are structured

If the points are structured, you have a decent chance of constructing the mesh by yourself. Denote *P(i,j)* the point *(X[i],Y[j],Z[i,j])*, that is, the point whose first coordinate is the *i*-th number in the list of the *x*-coordinates, whose second coordinate is the *j*-th number in the list of *y*-coordinates and whose third coordinate is the *z*-coordinate corresponding to the first two. Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xahd2.png) illustrates.

[image: Explanation of *P(i,j)*]

Now you need to decide the orientation of your triangles. They all should be either positively (counter-clockwise) or negatively oriented (clockwise). Assuming you decide for negative orientation, you can now create the triangle connecting the points *P(i,j)*, *P(i+1,j)* and *P(i+1,j+1)*. See Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7JUU.png).

[image: The first triangle]

In the next step, you can create the neighbouring triangle with the same orientation, say *P(i,j)*, *P(i+1,j+1)*, *P(i,j+1)*. See the darker triangle in Figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kFdu.png).

[image: The second triangle]

Proceeding the same way for all suitable *i*'s and *j*'s, you can obtain all the necessary triangles.

The only missing part is the normal for each triangle. This you can compute with a [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) as suggested in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305642/how-to-find-surface-normal-of-a-triangle).

Now you are ready to write everything to your file. Following the description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)), for each triangle you write its normal and the three vertices.

### If the points aren't structured

In this situation you don't have much chance of creating your mesh without a significant study of meshing methods (you will probably need to learn about Delaunay triangulations). Fortunately, there are some libraries available. For instance, [Fade2.5D](http://www.geom.at/fade25d/html/) is a C++ library that can help you and it is free of charge for personal non-commercial research. Maybe there is something similar available for Python as well.